# Get target URL of clicked event - client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have to get the target URL when clicking on the menu or any link in the master page.

I have used the following code

```
var target = $(document.activeElement)[0].href;
```

Which works 90% correctly.Since when I click a link from a menu for the first time.It shows undefined.

That is I have Many Menus in the master page and each menu contains many navigations.When I click a navigation from a menu for the first time, it will not have the value.If I click any of the link from the same menu after that it shows correct target link.

Please help me to find a was to get the target URL.

Answer (score 8):

You can get the target url like this --

```js
$('a').click(function(event) {
  $('div').html(event.target.href);
  event.preventDefault(); // Used to prevent the page from redirecting to google.com, just used for demo, you can remove it in your actual if not needed
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">Link 1</a>
<a href="http://facebook.com">Link 2</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Link 3</a>
<div></div>
```

Just give the function a parameter, something like `e`, and use the e to get the target url(href)

Comment: Thank you, @Advaith. Some of my links are just pop-ups  I just want to do the action when navigating to another page only.

Comment: @Akhil no problem.   :)    .

Answer (score 1):

You can try following solution to get target for any anchor in page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "a", function () {
        var target=$(this).attr("href");
        if(target!=undefined){
            alert(target);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're dealing with a race condition here. I have no idea where you're trying to access that variable, but chances are that `document.activeElement` is not going to reference the DOM Element you're willing to get it's href off.

The documentation says : *Returns the currently focused element, that is, the element that will get keystroke events if the user types any. This attribute is read only.*

So you need to handle this on an onClick event handler of that element that you want to read it's href:

```
onMyButtonClick(event){
 event.target.href;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Burinmi. I have to get the href in  $(window).unload().And the event.target.href; is not getting, since I have to get this in my page even if I click a navigation from my master page.

Comment: I am getting the target URL the code which I have mentioned in the question.Only in some cases it shows undefined.

Comment: @Akhil I feel you bruv, but you have to make some effort to make this work as I can't and I wont deal with the very specific problem of yours.